# Cross-browser XML Data Islands that can contain script tags

Tags: html, xml, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm interested in embedding SCXML, an XML application for describing Statecharts, into HTML. Internet Explorer has what are known as "XML Data Islands", which provide an elegant solution to this problem. Alternatively, IE9 and most modern non-IE browsers allow content to be served as XHTML, which allows mixing different document types in order to create compound documents by using XML namespaces. Furthermore, there is [this advice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_XML_Data_Islands_in_Mozilla) which I found on Mozilla's wiki which seems to offer an HTML5-approach (I use that term extremely loosely here), to XML Data Islands.

The Mozilla approach would seem to provide the best overall technique for embedding XML content in an HTML page. The problem is that it does not work if the embedded XML content contains a "</script>" tag, which is a part of the SCXML grammar.

Is there an elegant, cross-browser method to embed arbitrary XML content in an HTML page, including that which contains script tags?

Comment: What is cross-browser by your standards? Can you for example give us a definitive list? Also have you tried something that doesn't work? Finally what do you plan to do with that XML once it reaches the client browser, run XSL, run Javascript?

Comment: Cross-browser: IE 8+, recent Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari. The example listed on the linked mozilla article does not work if you add a script tag to the embedded XML - the page fails to parse in Mozilla (although works in Chrome). Finally, I'm planning to use JavaScript and DOM to manipulate the embedded XML content once it reaches the browser client.

Answer (score 1):

Process and a rest of SCXML alone – ask ID/IDREF so that we know that partial of a SCXML relates to and put it in a removed block.

Answer (score 1):

some significant advantages to XML for  over XML Data Islands and MSXML.

1) XML for  uses ECMA and W3C Standards, XML Data Islands do not.

2) XML for  does not pose security risks, XML Data Islands can.

XML for 's technology works within the browser's security sandbox and has none of these issues.

3) XML for  does not require new software to be installed on the client machine, XML Data Islands and MSXML often do.

XML for  does not effect any other part of the user's system and needs no installation. Since XML for  is not distributed in binary form (as opposed to MSXML), fixes to your application need only be propagated to one place (the server) rather than out to each client.

4) XML for  is open source and Free software, XML Data Islands and MSXML are not.

When you download XML for  you get full access to the source code to see how things are implemented. You are also free to modify, fix and change the software as you see fit as described by the LGPL license. XML Data Islands do not give you this freedom.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding inside a script element is still the most popular choice, I think.
If you expect a  element inside your XML, you might want to:
a) use object element as a wrapper instead
b) use namespaces in your XML so it's scxml:script
c) use a different approach altogether such as passing around pre-rendered charts as images perhaps.
One more approach is to use SVG which is supported natively by the browsers so the manipulation should be a bit easier, depending on the exact requirements.
d) strip the embedded script element before including it with the page? SCXML allows ECMAScript, but I wonder would you want to execute them as part of the parsing?
e)process  and the rest of SCXML separately - apply ID/IDREF so that you know which part of the SCXML applies to and put it in a separate  block.